# Protect Groovy/BeanShell Generated Classes

Tags: encryption, groovy, beanshell

I'm planning to embed Groovy / BeanShell in my application but I'm concerned about protecting the script and any dynamically generated classes from being viewed and modified by users to access my application code. The script contain proprietary algorithms. How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 2):

You can compile groovy down to byte code http://groovy.codehaus.org/Compiling+Groovy. This will provide you with the same level of protection that you would get from any other compiled java. If that isn't enough then you might want to look at an obsfucator like this http://proguard.sourceforge.net/ which will make understanding the decompiled code much more difficult.